# Deep / Nested Dependency Injection in testing

Tags: junit, mockito, mockmvc

I am using junit, mockito and mockMVC to test the working of a webapp. I am struggling with a dependency whose injecttion I cannot figure out. My webapp structure is as follows.

```
Class Controller{

    @Autowired Service searchService;

    @RequestMapping("Search")
    public returnType search(@RequestParam("parameter")String parameter){
        searchService.doSearch(parameter);
    }        
}
```

and the service class

```
Class Service{
    @Autowired Service2 service2;

    public returnType doSearch(String parameter){
        //some code
        service2.call(parameter);
    }
}
```

I need to test the search method for this controller, however service2 is not currently live and hence calls to it have to be mocked. I can mock service2, but cannot figure out how to inject a mock of service2 in my mockMVC instance of controller. As far as I know @InjectMocks in mockito only injects mocks one level deep and not two.

EDIT:

I am using the following to get MockMVC instance of controller

```
MockMvc controller;
controller = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(Controller);
```

Comment: In order to mock Service2 ,you need to have access to spring context that is getting created during your unit test.
There are multiple ways you can get access to spring context , you can autowire Application context and then inject the mocked object of Service 2 as a primary candidate for autowiring, or best way will be to write it a spring's xml if you have one that is getting used for creating test spring context.

Answer (score 1):

What you are essentially want to do is mock a bean.

In your case, you have to mock bean for service2 using @MockBean annotations.

Please refer [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that.

Mocking `search service` will be sufficient as you get the handle of what needs to be done.

Example:

`doReturn(...).when(searchService).doSearch(any());`

> While performing Unit Testing, the developer need to identify the *System Under Test* and mock/stub all the collaborators.

So, in this case you would write a separate unit test for Controller and Search Service.

Also, read [this](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) brilliant article by Martin Fowler - [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).

Comment: but then I won't be able to test the working of search class as well. I want to test all the systems that can be live during the test.

Comment: While performing Unit Testing, you should mock/stub all the collaborators. You need to write separate unit test for Search Service, wherein you will mock Service2.

Comment: I bypassed the problem by directly using searchService in my test class as controller was just passing parameters to it. However, if such injection is possible, please let me know. Thanks